# Admob GDPR UMP Issue: Empty IAB TCF Strings on Android After User Consent

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, admob, ump

I’ve encountered an issue with implementing the Admob UMP solution in Unity. After obtaining user consent, I need to check the provided consent. On iOS, I can easily access and analyze the IAB TCF Strings through PlayerPrefs. However, on an Android device, the IAB TCF strings are always empty.

Even after waiting for some time, they remain empty. Upgrading to the latest Admob version hasn’t resolved the issue.

Do you have any suggestions or ideas on how to address this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Recently encountered the same error, and the problem is that UMP does not write the IAB TCF keys in Unity's implementation of shared preferences on Android (PlayerPrefs). Google Admob 8.7.0 package for Unity provides getters for those keys in their ApplicationPreferences class, that wasn't present in previous releases (you can also find it in the changelog [here](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-unity/releases))

Obtaining keys worked on Android with the following example

```
string purposeConsents = ApplicationPreferences.GetString("IABTCF_PurposeConsents");
```

If for any reason you can't update to this version, you can write a getter for shared application preferences, following the guideline provided for Android's version of the Admob SDK, using as reference 'How to read consent choices' in this [guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/privacy/gdpr)